# AS3 Sync Data to Email

Tags: actionscript-3, email, flash, synchronization

I am making an mobile app in flash cc. I will make the pc version of the app also. The app saves some data as an object. I want that if I change some data in the mobile app, I will get the changed data in the pc version also. My brother told me that I can sync the data to email to do the job.

**How can I sync data to an email and get the synced data back in as3? If I can't, is there any other way to achieve the goal?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea about the email thing, but you could easily for example use php to sync your data to MySql database. [random tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-flash-login-system-using-php-and-mysql-part-1--active-5147)

Comment: Have you asked your brother *how* to "sync the data to email"? Honestly, that probably isn't the best route to go down. Otherwise, can you explain exactly the flow you expect? You can use email to transport messages, which could contain data your apps can understand, but its still going to require the user to open the email and do something. A better way to sync is with a server, like @randomtutorial said, so the apps only need to be open.

Comment: @Aaron Well, flash cc has an option to sync settings by email. I just thought of something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided much detail, but I can tell you that this probably isn't your best solution.

Email can't be used as a transparent sync layer. In other words, it will require the user to open the email and do something. Using a server is much better because then you can sync data without requiring the user to do anything besides use your app. You can also use existing syncing services like [DropBox](https://code.google.com/p/dropbox-as3/).

As for syncing by email, what you could do is create a [file association](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5f3b-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e18) which contains plain-text data (safe for email), such as JSON or XML. Then when a user receives an email they open the file, which will invoke your app with the file reference, and you can read the file.